# Regex pattern to separate values using comma but retain commas used within parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to modify a regex expression so that it retains commas used within parenthesis and separate all other values.

Existing pattern : `([^\\s,]+)\\s*=>([^,]+)`
Updated pattern : `([^\\s,]+)\\s*=>([^(,)]+)`

Java code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String softParms = "batch_code => 'batchCd',user_id => 'SYSUSER',thread_pool => 'tpName',business_date => FN_DATE_ARG(null,0),rerun_number => 0,max_timeout_mins => 0,raise_error => false,thread_notifications => false";

         //Pattern paramPattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s,]+)\\s*=>([^,]+)");
        Pattern paramPattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s,]+)\\s*=>([^(,)]+)");
        Matcher matcher = paramPattern.matcher(softParms);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String param = matcher.group(1);
            String value = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println("Param: " + param + ", Value: " + value);
        }
    }
```

The param value for **business_date** should come as `FN_DATE_ARG(null,0)` but the function is either returning `FN_DATE_ARG(null` or `FN_RMB_DATE_ARG`

Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Have you tried an online [regex tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
([^\s,]+)\s*=>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*,\s*\w+\s*=>|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pc9g4C/1). Details:

- `([^\s,]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace and a comma
- `\s*=>\s*` - `=>` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*,\s*\w+\s*=>|$)` - up to the leftmost sequence of 0+ whitespaces, comma, 0+ whitespaces, 1+ word chars, 0+ whitespaces, `=>`, or end of string.

In your code, use

```java
Pattern paramPattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s,]+)\\s*=>\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*,\\s*\\w+\\s*=>|$)");
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/EmbL4a).

Answer (score 2):

Why use an overly complex regular expression when all that is needed is a single one-line call to `String#replaceAll`:

```java
String softParms = "batch_code => 'batchCd',user_id => 'SYSUSER',thread_pool => 'tpName',business_date => FN_DATE_ARG(null,0),rerun_number => 0,max_timeout_mins => 0,raise_error => false,thread_notifications => false";
String businessDate = softParms.replaceAll(".*\\bbusiness_date => (.*?)\\s*(?:,[^,\\s]+ =>.*|$)", "$1");
System.out.println(businessDate);
```

This prints:

```
FN_DATE_ARG(null,0)
```

The regex pattern will match the key `business_date` followed by `\\s*,[^,\\s]+ =>`, which in this case will match the text  `FN_DATE_ARG(null,0)`.  The `(.*?)` matching group will stop matching at the comma before the next key.

Comment: This is a wrong answer because you only extract a single value while OP asks to extract all key value pairs.